# Searching all database schemas - how to use wildcards?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Using sqlworkBench I'm looking for column names. I'd like to use wild cards in my search using the below query. when I search for column "activated_at" it works but searching with wild card fails, can anyone help ?

```
SELECT 
    table_schema,
    table_name, 
    column_name, 
    data_type,
    ordinal_position

FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 

WHERE column_name = 'activated_a*' ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type, ordinal_position
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name LIKE 'activated_a%' ;
```

When you want to use wildcard, you have to use LIKE instead of '='

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `LIKE` instead of `=`.

So, something like this:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type, ordinal_position
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name LIKE 'activated_a%' ;
```

`%` is the wildcard character used by MySQL.  See the [MySQL documentation for string comparisons](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for further details.